# unrecognized selector exception when handling sudzc.com soap result

Tags: iphone, objective-c, selector, unrecognized-selector, sudzc

I have build an app around the sudzc.com generated code to access my soap web service. 
The soap request and the handling are placed in my UITableViewController subclass.

This is the relevant code:

```
 1 - (void)viewDidLoad {
 2 [...]
 3 NSLog(@"Starting Soap Request");
 4 CCExample_ManagerService* soapService = [[CCExample_ManagerService alloc] init];
 5 [soapService getActiveVehicles:self action:@selector(getActiveVehiclesHandler:)];
 6 }
 7
 8 - (void) getActiveVehiclesHandler: (id) value {
 9 [...]
10 }
```

I'm getting the following exception at line 5:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x112730'

After a lot of searching, I am really desperate, since the selector method is in the same class and thus visible. The very same code is also perfectly working in another project, so I'm unsure what prevents it from running in this particular case.

Comment: can you show the entire .m file..?

Comment: You are not showing enough code, but I have had a guess at answering anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere you are creating an `NSArray` and then later trying to add an object to it.  `NSArray` is immutable and doesn't respond to `-addObject:`.  So look for where you are creating or getting an `NSArray` - probably somewhere in `getActiveVehiclesHandler:` - and make it an `NSMutableArray` instead.

Comment: unfortunately, the error also occurs if I comment out everything in getActiveVehiclesHandler. I'm not adding anywhere anything to a "NSArray"

Comment: @user1365464: All the same, you still need to look for somewhere where an NSArray is being used in a mutable way.

Comment: solved! you were right. there was a cast to NSArray in the auto-generated sudzc code: SoapRequest* _request = [SoapRequest create: _target action: _action service: self soapAction: @"http://www.myURL/soap#getActiveVehicles" postData: _envelope deserializeTo: [[NSArray alloc] autorelease]]; Changed it to NSMutableArray and now it runs!